# HDD connected without a SATA power connector

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I was adding a second hard drive to my PC while I spotted that my other, 7 years in usage 3.5 hard drive (Seagate Barracuda 7200.12) was not connected to the PSU through the power connector, meaning that only the SATA interface port was connected. Yet, I have never experienced any problems with it, so the question is, is it okay to continue to use the drive like this, and how does the drive itself powers up without a power connector?

## Edit: the connector

[image: Cable]

I can’t even tell what is this cable for.

Comment: I'm gonna have to say, "photograph or it didn't happen" ;) It has to get power from somewhere & that somewhere is not the SATA data bus.

Comment: @Tetsujin, basically it was connected to something like a two-sided SATA power connector, which was not connected to anything. Considering the fact that external HDD do not require a power connector, it should be possible.

Comment: eSATAp can run without power, as it takes it from the USB bus. USB, of course, carries power. SATA alone does not carry power on the data port - http://www.interfacebus.com/SATA_Pinout.html

Comment: Quick test. Shut down. Pull the power plug out of the drive. Boot. Test.

Comment: I can see it is not connected to anything. And also, on this sata cable there are 5 wires not 4 as on the one, that is actually connected to the PSU.

Comment: Photographs. Plugs, sockets.

Comment: @Tetsujin edited, attached a photo.

Comment: Your photo shows a dangling power connector. It does not show the HDD not being connected to any.

Comment: The cable is probably similar to this one: https://asset.conrad.com/media10/isa/160267/c1/-/en/713256_BB_00_FB/image.jpg

Comment: @DanielB this is the exact cable my drive was connected to. I disconnected it for clarity.

Comment: You disconnected. Does the drive work when disconnected?

Comment: I'm not convinced, for at least 2 reasons. 1 as already stated, it's got to have power. 2. No-one is going to make a cable with just 2 SATA power plugs, one at each end. Non-smart plugs have to be different at both ends so you can't plug them up wrong. Clip that cable-tie so you can properly see where it goes… or do the test  mentioned earlier, pull it from the drive & see if it powers up.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, the disk won't work when the power connector is off. I still have no idea how it is connected to the PSU, but anyways, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Clip the cable tie & have a proper look. The only logical conclusion is it must go somewhere else that you can't see with it all bundled together.

Comment: I would recommend you "iTs.SL4y3R" (Why did you choose such an uncomfortable name?) to publish a detailed wiring diagramm with the status ante involving PSU, mainboard and drive. Otherwise everything is just guessing in the dark.